# android - start animation

Tags: java, android, animation

I want to start an animation after the user did a swipe gesture. I have a class where I set the animation and a class which is detecting the swipe. My problem is that I don't know how I combine them - I don't want my animation to start without a gesture. Do I need to start the animation method in the if-statement of the GestureDetector? And how do I start the animation from there in case I need to do that?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnGestureListener
{
            private ImageView imageView;
            private BitmapDrawable ball;
            float x1,x2;
            float y1, y2;
            Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {                       
                        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);                       
                        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);                        
                        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview1);

            }        



                        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent touchevent)
                        {
                                     switch (touchevent.getAction())
                                     {
                                            // when user first touches the screen we get x and y coordinate
                                             case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                                             {
                                                 x1 = touchevent.getX();
                                                 y1 = touchevent.getY();
                                                 break;
                                            }
                                             case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                                             {
                                                 x2 = touchevent.getX();
                                                 y2 = touchevent.getY(); 

                                                 //if left to right sweep event on screen
                                                 if (x1 < x2 && (x2-x1)>=(y1-y2) && (x2-x1)>=(y2-y1))
                                                 {      
                                                    imageView.animate()
                                                        .translationX(-imageView.getWidth()) //in this case Image goes to the left
                                                        .setDuration(180) //it's optional
                                                        .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                                                                 @Override
                                                                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                                                                    super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                                                                }
                                                    })
                                                    .start();

                                                    Toast.makeText(this, "Left to Right Swap Performed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                                              
                                                  }

                                                 // if right to left sweep event on screen
                                                 if (x1 > x2 && (x1-x2)>=(y1-y2) && (x1-x2)>=(y2-y1))
                                                 {
                                                    imageView.animate()
                                                        .translationX(imageView.getWidth()) //in this case Image goes to the right
                                                        .setDuration(180) //it's optional
                                                        .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                                                                 @Override
                                                                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                                                                    super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                                                                }
                                                    })
                                                    .start();
                                                     Toast.makeText(this, "Right to Left Swap Performed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                 }

                                                 // if UP to Down sweep event on screen
                                                 if (y1 < y2 && (y2-y1)>=(x1-x2) && (y2-y1)>=(x2-x1))
                                                 {
                                                     Toast.makeText(this, "UP to Down Swap Performed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                 }

                                                 //if Down to UP sweep event on screen
                                                 if (y1 > y2 && (y1-y2)>=(x1-x2) && (y1-y2)>=(x2-x1))
                                                 {
                                                     Toast.makeText(this, "Down to UP Swap Performed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                  }
                                                 break;
                                             }
                                     }
                                     return false;
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you want to implement here? As I understood, you want to animate `ImageView`, right?

You can use an `ViewPropertyAnimator` here instead of creating customized class.

Comment: ViewPropertyAnimator? Can I implement it into the detection class then? And yes, i want to animate the image by swiping

Comment: What kind of animation do you want to implement?

Comment: I think that's a ViewAnimation. The animation works, the image is moving from the center from the right, but the animation starts as I start the application, because I don't know how to conect it to the GestureDetector so the animation is waiting for a swipe

Comment: If user swipes to the left or to the right,  `ImageView` supposed to vanish or what?Because, I didn't understand what exactly it has to do

Comment: When the user swipes from left to right, the image is flying the the right outside the screen. When the user swipes to the other side the image flies to the left

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move your `ImageView` add this piece of code in your `GestureDetector` implementation according to the kind of user swipe.

```
imageView.animate()
        .translationX(-imageView.getWidth()) //in this case Image goes to the left
        .setDuration(180) //it's optional
        .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                         @Override
                         public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                             super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                             //insert some code here if you want to make some changes to the image instance when animation is finished

                         }
                     })
            .start();
```

You can add this code here, for example:

```
   public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent touchevent)
                    {
                                 switch (touchevent.getAction())
                                 {
                                        // when user first touches the screen we get x and y coordinate
                                         case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                                         {
                                             x1 = touchevent.getX();
                                             y1 = touchevent.getY();
                                             break;
                                        }
                                         case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                                         {
                                             x2 = touchevent.getX();
                                             y2 = touchevent.getY(); 

                                             //if left to right sweep event on screen
                                             if (x1 < x2 && (x2-x1)>=(y1-y2) && (x2-x1)>=(y2-y1))
                                             {      
                                                imageView.animate()
                                                    .translationX(-imageView.getWidth()) //in this case Image goes to the left
                                                    .setDuration(180) //it's optional
                                                    .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                                                             @Override
                                                            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                                                                super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                                                            }
                                                })
                                                .start();

                                                Toast.makeText(this, "Left to Right Swap Performed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                                              
                                              }

                                             // if right to left sweep event on screen
                                             if (x1 > x2 && (x1-x2)>=(y1-y2) && (x1-x2)>=(y2-y1))
                                             {
                                                imageView.animate()
                                                    .translationX(imageView.getWidth()) //in this case Image goes to the right
                                                    .setDuration(180) //it's optional
                                                    .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                                                             @Override
                                                            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                                                                super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                                                            }
                                                })
                                                .start();
                                                 Toast.makeText(this, "Right to Left Swap Performed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                             }

                                             // if UP to Down sweep event on screen
                                             if (y1 < y2 && (y2-y1)>=(x1-x2) && (y2-y1)>=(x2-x1))
                                             {
                                                 Toast.makeText(this, "UP to Down Swap Performed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                             }

                                             //if Down to UP sweep event on screen
                                             if (y1 > y2 && (y1-y2)>=(x1-x2) && (y1-y2)>=(x2-x1))
                                             {
                                                 Toast.makeText(this, "Down to UP Swap Performed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                              }
                                             break;
                                         }
                                 }
                                 return false;
                    }
```

I hope this code gives you ideas!

Comment: Looks good so far, but where do I add it? At the animation class? I'm pretty new to it, so I have problems to set it up, sorry for that

Comment: You've gotten an answer, I hope.

Comment: Thank you very much. Is my animation class not necesary any more?

Comment: Yes, you don't need that. Use simple `ImageView` in your XML or whatever. Here is a good tutorial about animations, it will help to make it clearer:https://guides.codepath.com/android/Animations

Comment: I edited the question - the code looks very good, but because of some reason the app crashes. I'm using the code I edited and deleted my AnimationClass